# 10.04 server to 12.04 server or 11.10 server to 12.04 server?

Tags: server, upgrade, 12.04

Will 10.04 x64 server have a smooth upgrade to 12.04 x64 server?

Will 11.10 x64 server have a smooth upgrade to 12.04 x64 server?

I am setting up a new production server this month, and I need to decide which to use.  I have been testing software on both.  11.10 has been flawless for me, and 10.04 has been a little rocky with the same packages.  I would like to be able to upgrade the server to 12.04 6 or so months after it comes out.

What are your thoughts on which one to choose in regards of a smooth transition to 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it will be much the same as it was last time there was a new LTS.  It's documented [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades).

Essentially, you should be able to do either.  I would think with a 'production server' the changes in UI packages aren't going to matter that much as long as you don't highly customize something.